# SPWeb = this.Web always points to Central Administration?

Tags: custom-actions, spcontext

I'm learning SharePoint 2010 and facing a strange problem :

I implement a custom action to add a ribbon button under Documents tab, this button has a command to  open a modal dialog in my site which is being located at `http://sharepointserver/dev/` . 
The Url parameter of showModalDialog function is pointed to my application page : test.aspx. The code of test.aspx.cs as below:

```
     ......................
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb web = this.Web;
            try
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[this.TargetListId];
                SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(this.TargetItemId);
            }
    }
```

My problem here is **this.Web** always points to `http://sharepointserver`, not my current site 
`http://sharepointserver/dev/`. This results in list #notfound when I execute **SPList list = web.Lists[this.TargetListId]**

My Sharepoint project Site URL is `http://sharepointserver/dev/` and Feature Scope is being set to Web so I don't know why **this.Web** doesn't want to give me the current site address. (SPContext.Current.Web also has a same problem)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok guys, I just created a new project with the same site collection and it worked fine, there must be some wrong configuration in my old project which I still don't know why. Anyways, thanks for all your help, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

is the link to your application page pointing to `http://sharepointserver/dev/_layouts/test.aspx`
or
is the link to your application page pointing to `http://sharepointserver/_layouts/test.aspx`

It should be the first if is the second this will explain your problem.
if not then the question will be is dev/ as sub site or a managed path site collection ?

Comment: My Application page url is : http://sharepointserver/dev/_layouts/SharePointProject1/test.aspx . dev/ is a managed path site collection

Comment: OK just created a site under an explicit managed path and an application page and this.Web is returning the right web see image [link](http://imgur.com/Dzd1y)

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that you cant use this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        try
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists[this.TargetListId];
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(this.TargetItemId);
        }
        catch(exception a)
        {
        }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx

but you can use this:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
            try
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[this.TargetListId];
                SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(this.TargetItemId);
            }
            catch(exception a)
            {
            }
    }
}
```

can you explain where your putting the code? as i can see page_load event (asp.net code behined) or webpart within feature or within feature reciver?

hope it helps :)

Comment: SPContext.Current.Web didn't work either :(. I'm putting the code in asp.net code behind

Comment: ok iv ammended the second part (code) instead of context iv used the httpcontext :)

Comment: if it doesnt solve your issue than please debug your code by putting a break point at the url part to see where its comming from, the current context is probably correct in showing you that result as in that moment in time the current context is that url your being displayed ;) !

Answer (score 0):

pls use like this for current web...

```
SPWeb spweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
```

or

```
using (SPSite spsite=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
      using (SPWeb spweb=spsite.OpenWeb())
      {
          // you can access current spweb object
      }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but he said, that it doesn't work for him as well.

Comment: try option from both of one...

Comment: from both of one option must be worked.

Comment: Both didn't work :(